# Rebooting From CloudFormation::Init Command

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I'm having trouble rebooting my EC2 instance from a `cfn-init` command. I have the following config key in my instance's `CloudFormation::Init` metadata.

```
dns-hostname:
  commands:
    dns-hostname:
      env: { publicDns: !Ref PublicDns }
      command: |
        old=$(hostname)
        sed "s|HOSTNAME=localhost.localdomain|HOSTNAME=$publicDns|" --in-place /etc/sysconfig/network
        echo HOSTNAME changed from \"$old\" to \"$publicDns\"
        reboot
      ignoreErrors: true
```

All the command is supposed to do is change the instance's hostname to the provided public DNS name. A reboot is required for this change to take effect, and since `cfn-init` doesn't know this, I have to include the actual call to `reboot` in the last line. Unfortunately, the build fails with the following log message (from `/var/log/cfn-init.log`):

```
2017-04-16 12:16:00,301 [DEBUG] Running command dns-hostname
2017-04-16 12:16:00,301 [DEBUG] Running test for command dns-hostname
2017-04-16 12:16:00,309 [DEBUG] Test command output: HOSTNAME will be changed to "bastion.example.com"
2017-04-16 12:16:00,309 [DEBUG] Test for command dns-hostname passed
2017-04-16 12:16:00,321 [ERROR] Command dns-hostname (old=$(hostname)
sed "s|HOSTNAME=localhost.localdomain|HOSTNAME=$publicDns|" --in-place /etc/sysconfig/network
echo HOSTNAME changed from \"$old\" to \"$publicDns\"
reboot
) failed
2017-04-16 12:16:00,321 [DEBUG] Command dns-hostname output: HOSTNAME changed from "ip-10-0-128-4" to "bastion.example.com"
/bin/sh: line 3: reboot: command not found
2017-04-16 12:16:00,321 [INFO] ignoreErrors set to true, continuing build
```

Clearly, the actual hostname change is not failing, just the call to `reboot`. I get the same error message if I try to use `shutdown -r` instead of `reboot`, and if I try to use an absolute path (`sbin/reboot`), then it just hangs and stack creation times out.  How are these very basic commands not found?  Am I missing something simple here? Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT**:  According to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/186808/every-command-fails-with-command-not-found-after-changing-bash-profile), when common commands are not available, it may be due to a screwed up `PATH`.  And indeed, the [CloudFormation::Init docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-init.html#aws-resource-init-commands) say that using the `env` property will overwrite the current environment, potentially including `PATH`.  However, I added a line to my template to `echo $PATH` inside the command, and that yielded: "`usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin`".  So my `PATH` still includes the path to the `bash` executable, and I am still confused...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it looks like the `env` property *was* the issue.  Even though I thought that my `PATH` still had the necessary paths to find the `bash` executable and thereby run the `reboot` command, it wasn't until I removed the `env` property from my template that everything was able to build successfully.  I still had some trouble getting the `reboot` command to behave as expected, as the command doesn't seem to run as soon as you call it.  For instance, the following code will output numbers 1-10 *before* rebooting.

```
echo 1
echo 2
echo 3
echo 4
echo 5
reboot
echo 6
echo 7
echo 8
echo 9
echo 10
```

So the instance would apparently try to reboot while in the middle of running other commands from later `CloudFormation::Init` configs, causeing `cfn-init` to fail.  My solution to this was just to run configs with `commands` blocks that manually called `reboot` after all other configs.  Long story short, here is the working template snippet:

```
other-config:
  ...

# This config comes after the other b/c it manually calls 'reboot'
dns-hostname:
  commands:
    dns-hostname:
      command: !Sub |
        publicDns=${PublicDns}
        old=$(hostname)
        sed "s|HOSTNAME=localhost.localdomain|HOSTNAME=$publicDns|" --in-place /etc/sysconfig/network
        echo HOSTNAME changed from \"$old\" to \"$publicDns\"
        reboot
      ignoreErrors: true
# Any other configs that call reboot can follow
```